# I can't show my data on a Javascript chart

Tags: javascript, charts, frontend, data-visualization, apexcharts

I created a webpage where some numbers are displayed in real time. The data is sent from a Python Flask script to my JavaScript frontend using SocketIO.

I'm now trying to show this numbers on a real time chart, and for that i'm using Apexcharts. The problem is that I'm not able to put on the chart what I need. I'm not getting any error at all, the chart won't work or display everything awfully.

As you can see, the data received from my socket is stored on numbers_received.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //connect to the socket server.
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
  var numbers_received = [];

  //receive details from server
  socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
    console.log("Received" + msg.number);
    //maintain a list of ten numbers
    if (numbers_received.length >= 1) {
      numbers_received.shift()
    }
    numbers_received.push(msg.number);
    numbers_string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++) {
      numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
    }
    s
    $('#log').html(numbers_string);
  });

  /*
      // this function will generate output in this format
      // data = [
          [timestamp, 23],
          [timestamp, 33],
          [timestamp, 12]
          ...
      ]
      */
  var lastDate = 0;
  var data = [];

  function getDayWiseTimeSeries(baseval, count, yrange) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
      var x = baseval;
      var y = numbers_received;
      data.push({
        x,
        y
      });
      lastDate = baseval
      baseval += 86400000;
      i++;
    }
  }
  getDayWiseTimeSeries(new Date('11 Feb 2017 GMT').getTime(), 10, {
    min: 10,
    max: 90
  })

  function getNewSeries(baseval, yrange) {
    var newDate = baseval + 86400000;
    lastDate = newDate
    data.push({
      x: newDate,
      y: numbers_received
    })
  }

  function resetData() {
    data = data.slice(data.length - 10, data.length);
  }
  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'line',
      animations: {
        enabled: true,
        easing: 'linear',
        dynamicAnimation: {
          speed: 2000
        }
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth'
    },
    series: [{
      data: data
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Dynamic Updating Chart',
      align: 'left'
    },
    markers: {
      size: 0
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      range: 777600000,
    },
    yaxis: {
      max: 100
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    },
  }
  var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#chart"),
    options
  );
  chart.render();
  var dataPointsLength = 10;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    getNewSeries(lastDate, {
      min: 10,
      max: 90
    })
    chart.updateSeries([{
      data: data
    }])
  }, 2000)

  // every 60 seconds, we reset the data 
  window.setInterval(function() {
    resetData()
    chart.updateSeries([{
      data
    }], false, true)
  }, 60000)

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to wait for `socket.on` to finish, before drawing the chart.

`socket.on` is asynchronous, which means all the code after that section,
will run before `socket.on` is finished, unless *by chance* `socket.on` runs really quickly.

try something *similar* to following setup (see `drawChart`)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //connect to the socket server.
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
  var numbers_received = [];
  var lastDate = 0;
  var data = [];

  //receive details from server
  socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
    console.log("Received" + msg.number);
    //maintain a list of ten numbers
    if (numbers_received.length >= 1) {
      numbers_received.shift()
    }
    numbers_received.push(msg.number);
    numbers_string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++) {
      numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
    }
    $('#log').html(numbers_string);
    drawChart();
  });

  function drawChart() {
    getDayWiseTimeSeries(new Date('11 Feb 2017 GMT').getTime(), 10, {
      min: 10,
      max: 90
    })

    var options = {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'line',
        animations: {
          enabled: true,
          easing: 'linear',
          dynamicAnimation: {
            speed: 2000
          }
        },
        toolbar: {
          show: false
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth'
      },
      series: [{
        data: data
      }],
      title: {
        text: 'Dynamic Updating Chart',
        align: 'left'
      },
      markers: {
        size: 0
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        range: 777600000,
      },
      yaxis: {
        max: 100
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      },
    }
    var chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#chart"),
      options
    );
    chart.render();
    var dataPointsLength = 10;
    window.setInterval(function() {
      getNewSeries(lastDate, {
        min: 10,
        max: 90
      })
      chart.updateSeries([{
        data: data
      }])
    }, 2000)

    // every 60 seconds, we reset the data
    window.setInterval(function() {
      resetData()
      chart.updateSeries([{
        data
      }], false, true)
    }, 60000)
  }

  function getDayWiseTimeSeries(baseval, count, yrange) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
      var x = baseval;
      var y = numbers_received;
      data.push({
        x,
        y
      });
      lastDate = baseval
      baseval += 86400000;
      i++;
    }
  }

  function getNewSeries(baseval, yrange) {
    var newDate = baseval + 86400000;
    lastDate = newDate
    data.push({
      x: newDate,
      y: numbers_received
    })
  }

  function resetData() {
    data = data.slice(data.length - 10, data.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's helping, indeed! I think i'm getting the hang of this.